# Efficiently Scrape Website Looping Through URLs

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, population

I am trying to scrape population data for each US state for a range of years.  Here is my code so far:

```
#Import libraries
import numpy as np
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

#Range of years
years = np.arange(1991,2019).tolist()

#Check to see if the website allows scraping
url = 'https://fred.stlouisfed.org/release/tables?rid=118&eid=259194'
page = requests.get(url)
page

#Set up dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'State':[''], 
        'Year':[''],
        'Population':['']
    }
)


#For each year - run through this process
for i in years:
    full_link = url+'&od='+str(i)+'-01-01#'
    page = requests.get(full_link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'lxml')
    
    
    
    #Grab the state names
    states = soup.find_all('span',class_='fred-rls-elm-nm')
    states_list = []
    for i in states:
        state_name = i.text
        states_list.append(state_name)

    #Package into df
    states_df = pd.DataFrame(states_list,columns=['State'])
    states_df['index'] = np.arange(len(states_df))
    
    
    #Grab the population values
    pops = soup.find_all('td',class_='fred-rls-elm-vl-td')
    pop_list = []
    for i in pops:
        pop_num = i.text
        pop_list.append(pop_num)


    #Package into a df
    pop_df = pd.DataFrame(pop_list,columns=['Pop'])
    
    #Clean up population values
    pop_df['Pop'] = pop_df['Pop'].replace('\n',"",regex=True).str.strip()
    pop_df['Pop'] = pop_df['Pop'].replace(',',"",regex=True)
    pop_df = pop_df.apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='ignore')
    #Grab every third value
    pop_df = pop_df.iloc[::3, :]
    pop_df['Pop'] = (pop_df['Pop']*1000).astype(int)
    
    #Create index for joining
    pop_df['index'] = np.arange(len(pop_df))
    
    #Combine dataframes
    full_df = pd.merge(
        states_df,
        pop_df,
        how='left',
        on=['index']
    )
    
    #Add in the year
    full_df = full_df.append({
        'Year' : i
    },ignore_index=True)
    
    
    #Collect all dataframes in a list
    df_lists=[]
    for i in df_lists:
        df_lists.append(full_df)
    
#Print the list of dataframes
df_lists
```

I have been able to get this script to work when I hard code the year into the URL, but that is really inefficient.  I want to be able to loop through the years in the URL and grab the population data and package together into a nice dataframe.  So I would expect the dataframe to look like this:

```
State          Year  Population
Alabama        1991  4567
Alaska         1991  4563
Arizona        1991  4532
.........................
West Virginia  2018  3454
Wisconsin      2018  3423
Wyoming        2018  9843
```

Can someone help point me in the right direction?  I feel like I'm close, but I'm missing one or two details somewhere.

Any help would be appreciated!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - mostly needed to differentiate the subscripts

```
#Set up dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'State':[''], 
        'Year':[''],
        'Population':['']
    }
)

list_of_dfs=[]

#For each year - run through this process
for i in years:
    full_link = url+'&od='+str(i)+'-01-01#'
    page = requests.get(full_link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'lxml')
    
    
    #Grab the state names
    states = soup.find_all('span',class_='fred-rls-elm-nm')
    states_list = []
    for j in states:
        state_name = j.text
        states_list.append(state_name)

    #Package into df
    states_df = pd.DataFrame(states_list,columns=['State'])
    states_df['index'] = np.arange(len(states_df))
    
    
    #Grab the population values
    pops = soup.find_all('td',class_='fred-rls-elm-vl-td')
    pop_list = []
    for k in pops:
        pop_num = k.text
        pop_list.append(pop_num)


    #Package into a df
    pop_df = pd.DataFrame(pop_list,columns=['Pop'])
    
    #Clean up population values
    pop_df['Pop'] = pop_df['Pop'].replace('\n',"",regex=True).str.strip()
    pop_df['Pop'] = pop_df['Pop'].replace(',',"",regex=True)
    pop_df = pop_df.apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='ignore')
    #Grab every third value
    pop_df = pop_df.iloc[::3, :]
    pop_df['Pop'] = (pop_df['Pop']*1000).astype(int)
    
    #Create index for joining
    pop_df['index'] = np.arange(len(pop_df))
    
    #Combine dataframes
    full_df = pd.merge(
        states_df,
        pop_df,
        how='left',
        on=['index']
    )
    year_pop = str(i)
    full_df['Year'] = year_pop
    
    
    list_of_dfs.append(full_df)
    
full_df = pd.concat(list_of_dfs)
full_df
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do it with pandas:

```
for x in range(1900, 2022):
    df_list = pd.read_html(f'https://fred.stlouisfed.org/release/tables?rid=118&eid=259194&od={x}-01-01#')
    print(df_list[0].head())
    ## do stuff with data, save it, merge dfs, etc
```